# Geodesic triangles and Gauss curvature of induced metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Let $V$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature $K(V) \leq -1$. Let $\Delta^2 \subset \overline{V}$ be a geodesic triangle in its universal cover. When is it true that the Gaussian curvature of the induced metric on $\Delta^2$ is less than $-1$? If it's true that the second fundamental form (relative curvature) of $\Delta^2$ is non-positive, one can use the Gauss equation. If you connect two vertices of the triangle using a geodesic curve, and then “fill” your triangle by considering all geodesics that connect the third vertex to the geodesic curve that connects the first two vertices, does this work?

Comment: What is a "geodesic triangle"? Usually they mean by this just a curve consisting of three pieces of geodesic. But to talk of a Gaussian curvature you need a surface.

Comment: Just meant - take the three geodesic line segments that bound the interior of a surface

Comment: And the question is about the Gaussian curvature of that surface

Comment: Which surface? You have a Riemannian manifold, presumably of dimension $\geq 2$, since you are talking of SECTIONAL curvature. Where is the surface?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Let $V$ be dimension $m$.  I’m assuming $\Delta^2$ is embedded as a codimension $m-2$ manifold with boundary, with boundary $\partial_{\Delta}$ equal to the curve consisting of three pieces of geodesic. I’m talking about the induced metric on this submanifold, and curvature tensor of it.

Comment: You can "fill" your triangle in multiple ways, and you can achieve positive curvature somewhere for any bounding triangle (fill the triangle however you want and make a connected sum with a very small 2 sphere which will have positive gauss curvature if it is small enough since at small scale a Riemannian manifold is Euclidean).

Comment: Think for a moment of ordinary $R^3$, with Euclidean metric. A geodesic triangle    (whose sides are straight lines) can have any curvature (positive or negative) at various points.

Comment: Great, thanks. How about, though, if you require that two vertices are connected by a geodesic, and you “fill” the triangle in by connecting points on this geodesic to the third vertex ONLY by a geodesic? In the case of $R^3$, this means no curvature. (It is just a solid triangle lying in a plane).  What happens in the general case?

Comment: @JohnRached, this last suggestion will depend on which vertex is the “third vertex”, and — like all definitions of filled-in triangles in generic Riemannian spaces — it is not clean enough to give an especially nice formula for the Gaussian curvature.

Answer (score 1):

It appears conditions for when this statement is true can be found here:

[https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/435.pdf](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/435.pdf)

Section 1.2, Theorem A

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the relevance of that theorem. As far as I can see, it only discusses the mass of the image of a map from a triangle, and only some map homotopic to the given map, and not a submanifold, not embedded or immersed, so doesn't have an induced Gauss curvature. Also, the map post homotopy isn't guaranteed a geodesic triangle, or even ruled by geodesics. Also, every map from a triangle is homotopic to a constant map, so the theorem doesn't help me at all with your question.

Comment: Indeed, that is all true. See page 19 “estimate of the volume of a straight simplex”, and the proof. The proof of theorem (A) constructs a specific homotopy, and this is applied on page 19.

Comment: In the sentence about geodesic triangles, I would interpret "geodesic triangles $\Delta^2 \subset \tilde{V}$" as "the images of maps from a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\tilde{V}$ which take geodesics to geodesics" -- those maps occasionally exist, but I don't see any guarantee of their existence in Gromov's offhand comment.

Comment: That’s fine. I’m fine with something weaker than my original question. I just wanted conditions under which one could say something like this